# Differentiate Uppercase Characters with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, character

I have a powershell script where I need to replace the following characters:

Ä = Ae, ä = ae, Ö = Oe, ö = oe, Ü = Ue, ü = ue

But if i run my script Powershell doesn't differentiate between uppercase letters and the lowercase letters.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, you can perform a **case-sensitive** comparison by using `-ceq` instead of `-eq`:

```
'Ö' -eq 'ö'
True

'Ö' -ceq 'ö'
False
```

See also: [PowerTip: Use PowerShell to Perform Case-Sensitive Comparison](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-perform-case-sensitive-comparison/?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)